# OpenSSL in a VisualC++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, openssl, winsock, winsock2

i'm trying to write a C++ DLL which uses openSSL to secure a connection to a server.

I'm genuinly puzzled by the fact that this code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
//SSL stuff
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
#include <openssl/ossl_typ.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>
//Winsock stuf
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
{... Create a method in which we set up the SSL connection ...}
char* tSend = "{\"reqtype\":\"keyexchange\"}";
int sendSize = strlen(tSend);
int net_tSend = htonl(sendSize);
SSL_write(ssl, &net_tSend, 4);
SSL_write(ssl, tSend, sendSize);
```

works fine in a Console application, but crashes in my DLL.
Here's my exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF865207DA0 (libeay32.dll) in TestsForPKCSDLL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: An AccessViolation when accessing an address at/near 0 means a NULL pointer is being accessed.  Find the NULL pointer in your code and fix it. The most likely culprit is your `ssl` pointer, or an `SSL_CTX` or `BIO` that it is linked to.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question (besides you are puzzled)?

Comment: @Dan: the message i quoted (Exception thrown at ....).

Comment: @jww: well, how to make it work of course.

Comment: @lieblo Of course it gives you that error message, but if you **break** the program at the point where the error occurs, you will see the call stack and be able to find the exact statement where the problem occurs. You have a powerful tool there, use it!

Comment: @Dan: My bad! Well the problematic statement is the call to htonl(). As i aded in my answer, i think that the problem occurs because the DLL doesn't include openSSL code, but references it. So if a program loads my DLL but not openSSL, the DLL code crashes (the function pointers in the libeay.lib point to zero).

Comment: What if you take care of loading the necessary dependency libraries in `DllMain` of your DLL? (or wait, isn't htonl from winsock? -- Ws2_32.lib/dll)

Comment: There's some weird stuff happening in my code... htonl() works fine if i include <Winsock2.h>, but my problem is that both SSL headers and Winsock2.h define a sockaddr struct, which leads to a compilation error. EDIT: i tried to send something with SSL without using htonl(), works fine...

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, it looks like the problem comes from the htonl() function.

```
    u_long mylong = 10L;
    int net_tSend = htonl(mylong);
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF863807DA0 (libeay32.dll) in TestsForPKCSDLL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Which apparently is not loaded properly. I think that, because my code is in a DLL, it crashes if the calling program doesn't reference SSL dlls. I'll try to link libeay32 and ssleay32 statically see if that works.