# OpenSSL RSA library throws exception

Tags: c++, dll, openssl

I would like to include RSA encryption to my `DLL` project written in C++ using `Visual Studio 2017`, and I decided that OpenSSL would be perfect. I've added correct path to my OpenSSL folder in `Additional Include Directories` and `Additional Library Directiories`, I've added `libcrypto.lib/libeay32.lib` to `Additional Dependencies`. The project compiles, but when I want to use some functions from `rsa.h` like `RSA_size`, I'm receiving exception like:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F17EB64 (libcrypto-1_1.dll) in Win32Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

I've assumed that this is because some pointer went NULL in the library, but I can't find the reason. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704926/openssl-in-a-visualc-dll) told me to try this library with regular exe application, but the same error occurs even with the simplest code

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
int main()
{
    RSA *m_rsa = RSA_new();
    RSA_size(m_rsa);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to implement OpenSSL in version `1.1.0` and `1.0.2`, both with same result.

RSA_new correctly allocates new RSA instance and ERR_get_error() returns "0".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the library documentation:

> If the allocation fails, RSA_new() returns NULL and sets an error code
>   that can be obtained by ERR_get_error(3). Otherwise it returns a
>   pointer to the newly allocated structure.

The RSA_new can fail an return a null pointer.
Using `RSA_size()` will use this null pointer (address 0) to access a field of the RSA structure. If this field is at the offset 4, you will try to access the address 4 (base address 0 + offset 4) and you will get an "Access violation reading location 0x00000004".

So, check the returned pointer. If null, check the error code to see what happened...

Library links:

- [RSA_new](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RSA_new(3))
- [ERR_get_error](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:ERR_get_error(3))
- [ERR_error_string](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:ERR_error_string(3))

Edit:

Another thing to know is that `RSA->n` should not be null when calling `RSA_size()` ([see documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RSA_size(3))). `n` is for the modulus, so you cannot call `RSA_size()` until you have generated or setted a key.

See this example ([permalink here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bfe4e0225d3e79e)):

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
int main ()
{
    RSA* rsa = RSA_new ();
    std::cout << "rsa pointer = " << rsa << std::endl;
    std::cout << "rsa->n = " << rsa->n << std::endl;
    RSA_size ( rsa ); // Seg fault.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
rsa pointer = 0x12d9c20
rsa->n = 0
bash: line 7: 10149 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Comment: Sorry that I've forgot to mention that the RSA pointer returned by RSA_new is actually valid (at least it is not a nullptr, and ERR_get_error() returns "0")

Comment: Ok, not familiar with this lib, but its seems that you should generate or set a key to be allowed to call RSA_size(). Answer completed with more details.

Comment: When I try to get anything from rsa object (like rsa->n) I receive `pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed`. Maybe this is a lead ?

Comment: After an investigation I've found out that RSA_new() creates new RSA pointer with 'n' set to 0 indeed. Is there any way to generate actual 'valid' key to perform operations on it? RSA_generate_key_ex shouldn't be needed here